# Wifi not working after migrating hard drive

Tags: drivers, wireless

I migrated my hard drive to a different laptop and I am having trouble getting my WiFi to work. `lshw` shows that the drivers are installed but `ifconfig`  only display ethernet and loopback. I've been looking for solutions for over a week now.

Can anyone suggest something I can do?
Thanks

Comment: Does the new laptop have the same wifi card as the old laptop?

Comment: It seems you're assuming there's some "generic wifi drivers". Absolutely not the case, different hardware, different drivers. In order to help you we need to know about the new hardware so please edit and post it.

Comment: @OrganicMarble the new laptop has a different wifi card.

Comment: @CelticWarrior  I actually downloaded and installed drivers for my specific wifi card.
This is the out put from lshw -c network (Ethernet adapter excluded)
*-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:fe8fc000-fe8fffff

Comment: @CelticWarrior I followed the instructions in the link you sent me and it worked. Thank you!